# How Can I Check if Every Item in a List Appears Within Any Items in Another List?

Tags: python, list

For example:
If I have 2 lists,

```
list1 = ["apple","banana","pear"]

list2 = ["Tasty apple treat", "Amazing banana snack", "Best pear soup"]
```

I would like to check if every string in list1  appears **in** any item in list2.
So in the example, it would get True in return.
But if list2 looked like this...

```
list2 = ["Tasty apple treat", "Best pear soup", "Delicious grape pie"]
```

...it would return false since "banana" doesn't appear in any items in the list.

I have tried by making a tfList that would hold True and False values and then I could just check if any items in the tfList were false.

```
tfList = []
for x in list1:
   if (x in list2):
      tfList.append(True)
   else:
      tfList.append(False)
```

I also tried this but it may have been a worse attempt:

```
if all(True if (x in list2) else False for x in list1):
```

The first one returned all False values and the second one didn't run the if statement as true and instead ran the else even though I used testing lists like the first examples.

**I'm very new to this so apologies if my attempts seem insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
find = True
for word in list1:
    auxFind = False
    for phrase in list2:
        if(word in phrase):
            auxFind = True
    if(not auxFind):
        find = False
print(find)
```

What it does is verify if every word in list1 appears at least one time on list2 and return True if does find.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if each string of `list1` is a sub-string of at least one element of `list2`.

The reason your first approach returns always `False` is because you are not checking if `x` appears in each element of `list2`, rather if `x` is an element of `list2`.

You could accomplish your goal by:

```
def appears_in(list1, list2):
    for word in list1:
        appears = False
        for sentence in list2:
            if word in sentence:
                appears = True
                break
        if not appears:
            return False

    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
all(
    any(
        word1 in map(str.lower, word2.split()) 
        for word2 in list2
    )
    for word1 in list1
)
```

Depending on how nice your inputs are, you can replace `map(str.lower, word2.split())` with `word2`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```
list1 = ["apple","banana","pear"]

list2 = ["Tasty apple treat", "Amazing banana snack", "Best pear soup"]

#return true/false for presense of list1 in any of items in list2
tf_list = [i in x for i in list1 for x in list2]

# if all items in list1 in list2
tf_list_all = all([i in x for i in list1 for x in list2])

# if any of items of list1 is in list 2
tf_list_any = any([i in x for i in list1 for x in list2])
```